# SlickGrid with first column fixed

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

Is it possible to make the first column of a SlickGrid fixed? So that it is always visible during horizontal scrolling, like the header-row?

Thanks for help!

Comment: so I found nothing in the source (version SlickGrid v2.0 alpha). Maybe the answer ist just "no".

Comment: Thee's an answer to the same question form the SlickGrid author here: http://groups.google.com/group/slickgrid/browse_thread/thread/ba6a85279f3cfd5f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can make in the event `.onViewportChanged()` the next steps:

1. Get the columns with `.getColumns()` and stored in an array variable `arrColumns`.
2. Then detect the first column.
3. Store the data with `.getData()` in an array variable `arrData`
4. Sort `arrColumns` putting the first column at the beginning.
5. Set the columns in the new `arrColumns` with `.setColumns()`
6. Reassembly `arrData` with the order of the new `arrColumns`.
7. Call `.resizeCanvas()`
8. Cross your fingers. :D

Sorry but I don't find a method or an option in that you can make this behavior in the way that you want.

Well, see what you think of [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Galled/HTmdp/88/). It is far from perfect, but it is an idea. I would make something better if the method scrollTo() would be public.

Comment: Why not try and make some tests?

Comment: not very performant because you have to handle all the data of the grid. next problem: horizontal scrolling is done pixel by pixel and not column by column.

Comment: That's a pretty awesome example.  All you'd have to do to make it perfect is offset that fixed column by the same number of pixels the other columns are.

Answer (score 12):

There was another forum link (can't find it now) that lead my to [JLynch's fork](https://github.com/JLynch7/SlickGrid/tree/2.0-frozenRowsAndColumns). He maintains both a 1.4.3 tag with his patches for frozen columns and rows, as well as maintaining a 2.0 head. Here is the 2.0 example with both [frozen rows and columns](http://jlynch7.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-frozen-columns-and-rows.html).

In that example, the author uses a couple additional options properties:

```
        ,topPanelHeight: 25
        ,frozenColumn: 2
        ,frozenRow: 5
```

Hopefully this does what you want without having to hack too much on the core!

Comment: his slickgrid.js different with normal, hard to do some update with new slickgrid version. We should find another way.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't fully match your needs, but you can completely avoid horizontal scrolling by setting `forceFitColumns` to true in the options object.

I reckon that this behavior would be undesirable for users with a very small screen.

Comment: No, he need something like freeze panes in Excel.